# How to initialize the value of state on the basis of props and then change the state on dropdown selection in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component with a dropdown having two options. 'Existing Members' and 'Add New Member'.

If the value of a props.existingMembers.length > 0. No default value should be selected in dropdown.
However if the props.existingMembers.length === 0. 'Add New Member' should be selected as the default value in dropdown.

In ComponentDidMount I am making an API call with the help of which props.existingMembers is fetched. Since props.existingMembers always have length 0 in first render(Before API call). I am unable to achieve above requirement.

```
class AssignOwnershipDialog extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            dropDownValue: '',
        };
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        fetchExistingMembersList();
    }
    static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
        if (props.existingMembers.length === 0) {
            return {
                dropDownValue: 'Add New'
            };
        }
        if (props.existingMembers.length === 0) {
            return {
                dropDownValue: ''
            };
        }
    }

    handleDropDownSelection = (dropDownValue) => {
        this.setState({
            dropDownValue
        });
    }

    render() {
   const {dropDownValue}=this.state;
        return ( <React.Fragment>
            <Select value = {dropDownValue}
            onChange = {(e) => this.handleDropDownSelection(e.target.value)}>
                <MenuItem value = "Add New" key = {0}> Add New </MenuItem> 
                <MenuItem value = "Existing Member" key = {1}> Existing Member </MenuItem> 
                </Select> 
                </React.Fragment>
            );
        }
    }
```

The above approach seems to be not working as the value of dropdown is not changing

Answer (score 0):

You can add an item with empty value so if the state is empty nothing will be shown in dropdown

there is a minor mistake

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    if (props.existingMembers.length === 0) {
        return {
            dropDownValue: 'Add New'
        };
    }
    // mistake
    if (props.existingMembers.length > 0) {
        return {
            dropDownValue: ''
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Rather how can I make sure a value is selected if some action is taken by the user on dropdown

Comment: You can check it in handleDropDownSelection function where you are getting dropDownValue as a parameter or if you are using some type of form and you want to get the dropdown value on submitting the form you can get it from the state. Hope this will help! Feel free to ask if you have any problem